# fail to install magento patch 6788

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, patch, magento-1.6

I was trying to install the new magento patch 6788 on my Magento CE1.6.1.0, but I cannot apply it successfully because of the following errors:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file .htaccess
Hunk #1 FAILED at 184.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.rej patching file .htaccess.sample 
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.0-1.6.1.1.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
 patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.phppatching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 48.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 66.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 176.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file 
......
```

I have replaced the two failed files (.htaccess and Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php) with the original magento files, but still getting the same error.

Please give me some ideas about why does it happen.

Thank you.

Comment: because your .htaccess is way too different than what the patch can handle?

Comment: The .htaccess file I have is not very different with the original one. They have the same number of lines. Besides, I have replaced the .htaccess file, but still got the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely seems to by the .htaccess file, try to find the exact version for the CE1.6.1.0. 
Also make sure that you don't deleted any file/folders from the original. I deleted some skins that I wasn't using (Modern and Iphone) and had to restore them. 
I also restored the .htaccess.sample file.

Comment: I just got it to work by replacing the .htaccess file, the error on the other file is gone too. Maybe I replaced the htaccess with a wrong file previously.

Thanks!!